# How to override a dependency properties in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-properties

So I have a class; lets use the `ScrollViewer` class as an example. It has a dependency property called `Content` which accepts anything of type `System.Object`, great!

Let's say I derive a class from `ScrollViewer`, lets call it `ZoomScrollViewer`, it adds some basic zooming and panning using the mouse with a keyboard press. It also adds a dependency property of it's own, `AutoscaleContent`.

Now, I want to be able to put a `ZoomScrollViewer` into a UI window, but I **only** want it to accept a Canvas as it's content. Naturally, I go about creating a `ZoomScrollViewer<T>` class.

However, how can I change the Content property so that only accepts elements of type `<T>`? Can I override the dependency property? I got a little confused and tried:

```
    public new T Content
    {
        get { return (T)base.Content; }
        set { base.Content = value; }
    }
```

But of course this makes it no longer a dependency property, so all the XAML code fails when I set up the bindings.

Edit: It should also be noted that I've taken a look at using:

```
ZoomScrollViewer.ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ZoomScrollControl2<T>), new PropertyMetadata(...?));
```

To see if I could do anything using that, but it seems you can only override the default value, unless I'm missing something?

Update: I've now tried using the following:

```
public class ZoomScrollControl2<T> : ZoomScrollViewer where T : FrameworkElement
{
    static ZoomScrollControl2()
    {
        ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ZoomScrollControl2<T>), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ZoomScrollControl2<T>)));
    }
}

public class CanvasZoomControl : ZoomScrollControl2<Canvas>
{
}
```

Which I thought would work, but it still seems to accept a Content of any type.

Update: In short I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible, so I've marked the discussion as the answer, even though it isn't an answer per-se.

Comment: so the `ZoomScrollViewer.ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ZoomScrollControl2), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ZoomScrollControl2))` doesn't work for you?

Comment: The line of code I've put in there doesn't do anything, what you've put is different however. Are you suggesting that as an answer?

Comment: I suggest to try that approach as it suggested by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) MSDN article. It *should* override the **referal** type, so you can refer to it using derived type.  **Dependency** property visibility is not made esplicit in .NET Framework for derived types, as searching right property among the types tree has a cost in terms of performance, and considering that we use DP on UI binding, it can lead to non desirable performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to try that approach as it suggested by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) MSDN article.

It *should* override the referal type, so you can refer to it using derived type.

`Dependency Property` visibility is not made esplicit in `.NET Framework` for derived types, as searching right property among the types tree has a cost in terms of performance, and considering that we use `DP` on UI binding, it can lead to non desirable performance issues.

Comment: Close, but no cigar.. Take a look at the Update I posted above, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Siyfion: why do not you use CanvasZoomControl, considering that it's last in dependency ierarchy?

Comment: I am in the *.xaml, I've got: `<CanvasZoomControl Grid.Row="2" ViewContent="{Binding Path= Cutlines}" />` whereby `Cutlines` is a Canvas property, but if I change it at the moment it just carries on regardless.

Comment: To me it seems that you need to define DP like `CanvasZoomControl .ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof(CanvasZoomControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CanvasZoomControl ))` so the property will "propagated" to that type.

Comment: Problem then is that each implementation of the generic class needs to be created manually in code... Perhaps what I'm asking isn't possible / isn't a good idea! I just see it as a way to have a control that works with anything, but can be restricted to only allowing use of one class if needed. That way you always know that if it has content, you can rely on it being of type `T`.

Comment: @Siyfion: if you want that DependencyProperty declared in base class is simply accessible in derived one in XAML, like any ordinary one, it's not possible unfortunately, for reasons described above. But the good news are, that you *should* be able to explicitly say: I want to be able to access my base class property from XAML from the *this* type, by overrideing metadata.